# CodeIgniter - Writing input array to database

Tags: database, arrays, codeigniter

I am trying to grab the data from an array of input fields and write them to a database. I have never worked with arrays before but this is the code I have. It is based off what I would do if it was just a single input value. I know this is wrong but I have no idea what to try next. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
//view
<input type="text" name="assignments[]">
<input type="text" name="hours[]">

<input type="text" name="assignments[]">
<input type="text" name="hours[]">

<input type="text" name="assignments[]">
<input type="text" name="hours[]">

<input type="text" name="assignments[]">
<input type="text" name="hours[]">

<input type="text" name="assignments[]">
<input type="text" name="hours[]">

//controller
$assignments = $this->input->post('assignments', TRUE);
$hours = $this->input->post('hours', TRUE);

$this->load->model('create', 'create_model');
$this->create_model->create_projects($assignments, $hours);

//model
public function create_projects($assignments, $hours) {

    $data = array(
        'assignments' => $assignments,
        'hours' => $hours,
        );
    $this->db->insert('projects', $data);
}
```

Comment: It depends on how you want your data to be represented in the database. You can't store arrays in a text field for example unless you serialize it (I suspect this is what you do as of now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks the answers. What ended up working best for me was this.

```
//controller
$assignments = $this->input->post('assignments');
$hours = $this->input->post('hours');

$this->load->model('create', 'create_model');

foreach($assignments as $key => $n){
    $this->create_model->create_projects($n, $hours[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can't put a PHP array in the database as is:

```
$data = array(
    'assignments' => $assignments, // this is an array
    'hours'       => $hours,       // so is this
);
$this->db->insert('projects', $data);
```

You need a string representation of the array, two options come to mind:

- [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)
- [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Personally I prefer json_encode as it is not dependent on PHP for reading, serialize is useful for storing PHP objects but you don't need that here:

```
$data = array(
    'assignments' => json_encode($assignments),
    'hours'       => json_encode($hours),
);
$this->db->insert('projects', $data);
```

Make sure your DB fields are `TEXT` type so they are able to store variable length data. When you fetch the data later, you will have to run `json_decode()` on each field to read it and turn it back into an array, for example:

```
$result = $this->db->get('projects')->result();
foreach ($result as $record)
{
    $assignments = json_decode($record->assignments);
    // Now $assignments is an array
}
```

Comment: This is great, but I think the result I am looking for is to have each `assignment[]` and `hour[]` in its own row in a table. Not the whole `assignment[]` array stored in the same table cel. I have been playing around with `insert_batch` to no success.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that would be a better solution but wasn't sure if you wanted to go that route. Maybe just run the INSERT query in a loop to check if that works then come back to `insert_batch` after you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

> **Simply use json_encode() function to store array data in the database**

```
json_encode(array('key' => 'value'))
```

**OR**

```
json_encode($_P0ST['ARRAY'])
```

**OR IN CodeIgniter**

```
json_encode($this->input->post('arraydata'));
```

Answer (score -1):

In post:-
$skills         = $this->input->post('skills[]',TRUE);

'skills'            => json_encode($skills) ,

It solved my problem.