# How to store the values of array in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, codeigniter

Is it possible to retrieve values from database as an array and save the same values back to the database?

For example, In my table1 it returns an array:

```
array(1) { 
   [0]=> string(5) "test1" 
}
```

I wanted to save **test1** back to my database.

Codes:

View

```
  <?php //for viewing data
  foreach ($users as $user) {
     echo $user->empID;
     echo '<br>';
  }
   ?>
   <?php //for inserting data
  foreach ($users as $row) {
     $rec_users[] = $row->empID;
  }
       echo form_multiselect('empRequired[]', $rec_users, $rec_users,  array('class' => 'chosen-select', 'multiple style' => 'width:785px;'));
?>
```

Controller

```
    $lid = $this->admin_model->getID();
    foreach ($lid as $id) {
        $last_id = $id['projectID'];
        $data['users'] = $this->admin_model->getUsers($last_id);
    }

    $this->load->view('admin/projects/rec-employee', $data);

$recommended = $this->input->post('empRequired');

foreach ($recommended as $row) {
   $data1 = array(
            'projectID' => $last_id,
            'username' => $row
   );

   $this->admin_model->insertRecEmp($data1);
}
```

Model

```
    public function insertRecEmp($data){
        return $this->db->insert('projectemp', $data);
    }


Table 1: primary key
+--------+
|username|
+--------+
| test1  |
+--------+

Table 2: foreign key

+--------+----------+
|empID   |projectID |
+--------+----------+
| test1  |          |
+--------+----------+
```

[image]

I want the test1 in the dropdown to be saved in my database, however when I click next, it results to

[image]

Instead of test1, it's returning 0.

Comment: You mean the VALUE within position 0? Here being "test1"

Comment: @clearshot66 yes sir.

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array: If you set up a database table with a column, just run a foreach($array as $value) then run an insert query to that column inserting $value

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp

Comment: @clearshot66 i did, still returning they key = 0.

Comment: What's your DB table look like that you're going to be pulling from

Comment: sorry, im using codeigniter. I edited my codes

Comment: Where is this array you're retrieving from the database? I only see code to save input from the form. If the array you want is the what you're saving to in the insertRecEmp() call why do you want to save and retrieve what you already have?

Comment: I still don't see what value you are trying to access...

Comment: @Pacio I have updated my code.
I'm getting the value from my primary key table, and get the same value to save to my foreign key table.

Comment: @pacio let's say I have test1 in my table 1 and displayed it in my view. AS of now, it is displaying as an array. Now, using the same value from my table 1 which is test1, i want to save the same value to my foreign key table. Now my problem is, It is saving 0 instead of test1

Comment: Sorry, still don't understand. I don't see you getting any values from tables in your controller, only input from the form and then an insert in your what I presume is your foreign key table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137462/discussion-between-pacio-and-blakcat7).

Comment: take a look at here:<br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944077/codeigniter-writing-input-array-to-database

Answer (score 0):

serialize the array and store that in the dbase instead

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: The serialize, it's saving the literal value

Comment: yes, I serialized and echoed, it's giving me this result "a:1:{i:0;s:5:"test1";}"

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
// $session_data contains a multi-dimensional array with session
// information for the current user. We use serialize() to store 
// it in a database at the end of the request. 
$conn = odbc_connect("webdb", "php", "chicken"); 
$stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, "UPDATE sessions SET data = ? WHERE id = ?");
$sqldata = array (serialize($session_data), $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']); 
if (!odbc_execute($stmt, $sqldata)) { 
$stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO sessions (id, data) VALUES(?,?)"); 
if (!odbc_execute($stmt, $sqldata)) { 
/* Something went wrong.. */ } 
}
```

### ?>

NOTE: If you want to get this data from database then use unserializ() , which help you to convert your string into array

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach is overwriting the $data1 array on each pass, the controller should be like this:

```
   foreach ($lid as $id) {
    $last_id = $id['projectID'];
    $data['users'] = $this->admin_model->getUsers($last_id);
}

$this->load->view('admin/projects/rec-employee', $data);

$recommended = $this->input->post('empRequired');

foreach ($recommended as $row) {
   //this line is the changed one
   $data1[] = array(
            'projectID' => $last_id,
            'username' => $row
   );

   $this->admin_model->insertRecEmp($data1);
}
```